# Is it needed to convert lat/lon to cartesian coordinates to plot points in a Java app?

Tags: java, canvas, coordinates, plot

I have several 2D points in latitude and longitude coordinates (in decimal degrees).
I want to plot them into a `JPanel` canvas.

Since latitude and longitude are coordinates in a *sphere* or *ellipsoid surface*,
do I need to **convert them to cartesian coordinates** (linear surface) first?

Comment: It depends on several factors including on how big of a bite out of the sphere you'll be displaying as the degree of distortion will depend on this.  Then what sort of projection do you desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a correct presentation: yes. You need a projection to a 2D surface.

If the coordinates are all in a rather small geographical area and accuracy is not a strict requirement, it may be OK to just interpret them as pseudo 2D coordinates.

Have a look at [OpenMap](http://www.openmap.org/). I used it for drawing small maps, wasn't too difficult. (and once you've plotted your coordinates, sooner or later you might be interested to add some political maps or other shapes)